# Jasmine test spec failing to pickup React import statement

Tags: reactjs, gulp, jasmine, karma-jasmine, babeljs

I am trying to write unit tests for my reactjs code using Jasmine with the Karma test runner - automated with gulp. I am having an issue where my test spec includes import statements which are then not being picked up by the test body.

Here is my test spec:

```
import React from 'react';
import Utils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import {MyClass} from "../Path/MyCodeFile.jsx";

describe('MyClass', function () {

    it('can render without error', function () {
        var component;

        var element = React.createElement(
            MyClass,
            {} 
        );

        expect(function () {
            component = Utils.renderIntoDocument(element);
        }).not.toThrow();
    });
})
```

My Karma config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            'spec/*[Ss]pec.js',
            'wwwroot/js/site.js'
        ],
        exclude: [
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'spec/*[Ss]pec.js': ['babel']
        },
        babelPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'env'],
                plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-umd"]
            }
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-babel-preprocessor'
        ],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity
    });
}
```

My gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Server = require('karma').Server;
gulp.task('unittest', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, function () {
        done();
    }).start();
});
```

And this is the message I get when running the task:

```
[21:17:11] Starting 'unittest'...
02 08 2018 21:17:13.030:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.5 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
02 08 2018 21:17:13.030:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
02 08 2018 21:17:13.046:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
02 08 2018 21:17:14.969:INFO [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket peUBczU20NB36DSvAAAA with id 73989234
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0) MyClass can render without error FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (spec/applicationSpec.js:31:43)
        at <Jasmine>
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.003 secs)
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.02 secs / 0.003 secs)
[21:17:15] Finished 'unittest' after 3.6 s
```

It's as if the import statement isn't there.

Comment: Try to change it to `import * as React from 'react'` and see what happens. I suspect that module interoperation doesn't work as expected for current Babel config.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work - React was set to an object with an undefined default property. I am looking at an alternative approach using browserify.

Comment: *React was set to an object with an undefined default property* - that's the point. Did you check what this object was? I suppose this was `React`. The problem is possibly caused by transform-es2015-modules-umd . Applying same Babel config as in your app would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

After some pain, I have found an alternative approach which successfully runs the tests. My new test spec:

```
describe('MyClass', function () {
    var React;
    var Utils;
    var MyClasses;

    beforeAll(() => {
        React = require("react");
        Utils = require("react-dom/test-utils");
        MyClasses = require("../Path/MyClass.jsx");
    });

    it('can render without error', function () {
        var component;

        var element = React.createElement(
            MyClasses.MyClass,
            {} 
        );

        expect(function () {
            component = Utils.renderIntoDocument(element);
        }).not.toThrow();
    });
})
```

and my updated Karma config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
        files: [
            'spec/*[Ss]pec.js',
            'wwwroot/js/site.js'
        ],
        exclude: [
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'spec/*[Ss]pec.js':  ['browserify']
        },
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [
                ['babelify', {
                    presets: [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        "@babel/preset-react"
                    ]
                }]
            ],
            extensions: ['.jsx']
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],    
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-babel-preprocessor',
            'karma-browserify'
        ],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity
    });
}
```